# How to remove the special characters and & tokens(Invalid xml tokens) from xml file before giving to xml.sax parser in python

Tags: python, xml, sax

Presently i am working on xml.sax parser to parse xml files

suppose i had following code

```
filepath = 'users/file.xml'

try:
    parser = xml.sax.make_parser( )
    parser.parse(open(filepath))

except (xml.sax.SAXParseException), e:
        print "*** PARSER error: %s" % e
```

**file.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<tag1>
  <tag2>
<P style="MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt" class="MsoNormal"><FONT size="3"><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: Symbol; COLOR: black; mso-ascii-font-family: 'Times New Roman'">�</SPAN><SPAN style="COLOR: black"><FONT face="Times New Roman"><SPAN style="mso-spacerun: yes">&nbsp; </SPAN>Position will manage 24 ED Rooms with 24/7 accountability<o:p></o:p></FONT></SPAN></FONT></P>
   <DIV>&nbsp;</DIV>
   </tag2>
</tag1>
```

When the parser reaches the & in div tag it stopping execution and displaying the following error

```
*** PARSER error: users/file.xml:5:1: not well-formed <invalid token>
```

How to remove or escape all the invalid xml tokens before giving to parser from the xml file, is there any function to escape & and special characters form the xml tags or else we need to loop through he xml file and remove each and every invalid token? but dont know how to do it. Can anyone please share the code of doing it.

Comment: I am almost sure that "�" is what you should avoid. You have to correctly encode it.

Comment: There are many issues with this XML snippet. You're using undefined references - &nbsp; is defined in HTML and is not generic XML. You also use an undefined namespace prefix "o", which is another error. I can't offer much advice, except to make sure that whatever is generating this output creates proper XML.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to ignore &nbsp; and special characters from xml tag before giving xml file to parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11625224/how-to-ignore-nbsp-and-special-characters-from-xml-tag-before-giving-xml-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to repair the bad XML. Fix the process that created bad XML in the first place. You haven't told us what program wrote this stuff. The whole point about XML is that it's a standard, and you only get benefits from it if people actually stick to the standard.

Comment: Its sometime required to ignore when you just want to go ahead and skip special character.

Answer (score 0):

That is not a good habit to repair the response. 
Special character is not possible to parse in android.

you need to change the special character..